# how to add css file in drupal 7?

Tags: drupal

I want to add new css file. I added the following line in my .info file:

```
stylesheets[all][] = css/layout.css
stylesheets[all][] = css/style.css
stylesheets[all][] = css/colors.css
stylesheets[all][] = css/imagehover.css
stylesheets[print][] = css/print.css
```

I flush all cache. just to be sure I inspect page source but I only see style.css has been included:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" `href="http://sinepulse.local/sites/all/themes/smart_sinepulse/css/style.css">`
```

What about the others css files. Whats wrong with my approach?

Comment: Are you importing these css files in your own `custom drupal 7 theme`?

Comment: Yes. I am importing these css files in your own custom drupal 7 theme

Comment: It might be possible that caching mode in your drupal website might be `disabled`. Check this specific SO post : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2610837/drupal-multiple-stylesheets?rq=1 on for more details

Comment: Do you have a html.tpl.php in your theme? If so, what does it look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this way not working then try another way to add CSS follow the code to your **template.php** file

```
function MYTHEMENAME_preprocess_html(&$variables){
  $theme_path = base_path() . path_to_theme();
  drupal_add_css($theme_path.'/assets/css/style.css');
}
```

If after that not import your CSS then the problem is catching.

Thank You.